# how to parse yin files with opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I tried to follow this wiki https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/developer-guide/yang-tools.html to make an example.

But I don't know how to initiate YinStatementStreamSource and can not found YangInferencePipeline in neon release.

below is my added dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-parser-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-parser-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>yang-model-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Add some more details to your question. It seems incomplete.

Comment: Right now,I am trying to parse yin files which is converted from yang files with ODL yangtools.